# What is $@ means?

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, cloudera

I am referring this [link](https://github.com/kadel/Dockerfiles/blob/master/cdh5/cdh5-namenode/run.sh) for installing cdh4.6.0. I don't understand the following command.

```
 hdfs namenode $@
```

And, when i try it in my machine, it keeps on running. I can't able to see the completion of execution with command prompt.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$@` are the command line parameter of the program.

if you call a program named `test.sh` in this way: `test.sh 1 2 3`
`$@` contains `1 2 3`